# Merge [web-audio] and [web-audio-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [web-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio) and [web-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio-api) refer to the same thing, have the same topic of questions, and even have the same tag excerpts.

They should be merged.

I recommend we keep the [web-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio-api) tag,

- it is [the official name](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/)
- "Web Audio" is the name of [the W3C Working Group](https://github.com/WebAudio), and they do deal with other APIs (which have their own tags).
- *(at a lower scale)* [web-audio-api's tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-audio-api/info) is way more complete than [web-audio's one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-audio/info)

However I think this needs a moderator's intervention since 1,514 questions have been tagged [web-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio), vs only 430 for [web-audio-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio-api), we thus largely bypass the 1.25 ratio.

Comment: @Kaiido, mods can't overrule the 1.25 ratio, _but_ there's a workaround, which is to synonymize and then swap.

Comment: @BhargavRao yes I actually saw [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384317/merge-wrap-content-with-android-wrap-content/384318#384318) that you did something to workaround a similar situation, so I thought asking for your help was the correct move.

Comment: @Kaiido, Oh yeah, that was a merge. We can go that route too. In this case I will synonymize and swap, and merge after a few days. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-audio-api/synonyms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@BhargavRao has resolved this issue.