# Merge [wrap-content] with [android-wrap-content]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed that a [android-wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wrap-content) existed, but there is already one [wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap-content) tag. These tags are the same, since all [wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap-content) questions are related to [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and should be merged.

This has been pointed out by Andrew T. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/383015#comment688958_383015) and as per [Fixing the un-prefixed Android tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252394) these tags should be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [just 1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48559907) in the [wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap-content) tag, which didn't have [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, and even that was referring to the Android wrap-content.

[wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap-content) had more than 1.25 times the number of questions as [android-wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-wrap-content), therefore we can't add as a synonym. But, here it is very clear that both of the tags are referring to the same wrap-content, I have now merged the tags, and added [wrap-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap-content) as a synonym.

The next step now is to add a tag wiki excerpt for the tags.